# Revisions Tab is not visible

Tags: entities

I updated Drupal to 8.6.16 version and after that Revisions Tab is disappeared.
Actually, all revisions are saved fine and I can see them because I have access to the page "xxx/revisions", but I don't have "Revisions" in the list of tabs.
Do you have some idea what is the problem?

Comment: Was there more than 1 revision listed when you accessed xxx/revisions? As I believe the tab is hidden if there's not more than 1 revision

Comment: Yes, there is more than 1 revision but Revisions is not visible.